# Moved Database Data files, now backups wont work

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, backup, database-backups

Im using SQL Express on a server. The space was limited on the C Drive so i decided to move the database data files to another drive "J".

I had stored procedures for creating full, differential and log backups however none now work. I have changed the details of where the files should be created and stored (I thought it would be as simple as that).

when right clicking on the database -> tasks -> backup and run the backup it comes up with "backup failed for server..." then "system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror: backupdatabase is terminating abnormally". the message appears when running the stored procedures too.

would anyone have any idea on how to resolve this or what the cause may be?

> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Rather than using the GUI, script out the backup script and run it. If (when) it fails put the error in your question.

Comment: There should be more error messages than that. (Also, add the errors to your qusetion, not the comments. Not all the volunteers will read (and shouldn't need to read) the comments, and without the errors, they can't help you).

Comment: Hi Larnu. I didn't add it in the first instance as i thought the GUI gave a more detailed error message which is the reason I added that to the detail of my question instead. thanks again for your advice.